# cant install jockey-gtk

Tags: lubuntu, jockey

i am trying to install jockey on lubuntu to resolve an issue with my ATH-AR5BXB63 wifi card and get this....

```
linuxtop@linuxtop-HP-G6000-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
[sudo] password for linuxtop: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ubuntu-drivers-common' instead of 'jockey-gtk'
ubuntu-drivers-common is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 89 not to upgrade.
linuxtop@linuxtop-HP-G6000-Notebook-PC:~$
```

no idea what it is trying to do but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Ubuntu 14.04? If that's the case, `jockey` is not being used anymore, that's why is telling you that `ubuntu-drivers-common` are already installed.

I'm not sure which is the default package manager in Lubuntu, but in the standard ubuntu you can run `software-properties-gtk` and navigate to the drivers tab. It has the same functions that jockey-gtk use to manage.